# Is the endorsement quorum lowered, when a baker loses its baking rights, after two double (pre-)endorsement in the same cycle?

Tags: consensus

Since I can't find my source for this information, I formulate this question in two parts:

1. If a baker is shlashed twice in the same cycle for double (pre-)endorsing he has no frozen_deposit.
   Does this result in him losing his baking/endorsing rights for the remainder of the cycle?
2. If 1. applies, is the quorum for block endorsement lowered? What happens when 34% of the total staking power double (pre-)endorses twice and loses its baking rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes; it effectively loses the rights, in that its blocks and consensus operations are not considered valid.
2. No, the quorum remains the same. So the chain halts in your scenario.